# Deleting a comment in belongs_to and has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am following Getting stated with rails simple Blog app.
In the last part while deleting a comment they have used

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

My question is why do they want to delete comment like that

```
@comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
```

when

```
 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

both returns the same @comment object. since id will be unique through out comments. why they want to take extra step in finding article.
May be because first we need to check if comment belong to that article or not before deleting? or is that rails way to delete when such kind of association is setup

Comment: No reason, it's a bad tutorial.

Comment: It's a precautionary step

Comment: You don't want to end up deleting comment which belongs to another article

Comment: It's a *broken* precautionary step that adds no value. You need to insure that the *user performing the deletion* is authorized to do so, not that the comment belongs to the article. There is no value in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, there is no value to this. Checking that a comment belongs to an article before deleting it is pointless, unless the article is used to tell whether the requesting user is authorized to perform the action.

As it stands, checking that the comment belongs to the given article adds *no* value to the system, as both inputs are supplied by the user, and neither one is verified to belong to the requesting user. There is **no** inherent value in "insuring" that the comment belongs to the article, it's redundant and adds unnecessary overhead and clutter. You should use [shallow nesting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) to unscope the comment's show/edit/update/delete paths from its article.